# How to know type of a linker

Tags: linker, language-agnostic

How can we know that which type of linker(static/dynamic) our system is using?

Is it decided on type of library(static/dynamic) we have used or is there any other thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *toolchain* (e.g. GCC + GNU binutils) will provide a *linker* (e.g. `/usr/bin/ld)`
that you use to link programs (whether statically, dynamically, or a mixture
of both) when you are *building* them.

Your *operating system* will provide a *dynamic linker* (e.g. /lib/ld-linux.so) that
loads the shared libraries (if any) required by a program and resolves symbol
references *at runtime*, in accordance with the information encoded in the
executable by the *linker* at *build time*.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry couldn't up-vote your answer as less reputation... Thanks again!

Comment: @DeadCode To [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) you click on the green checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

You are the master of your project. So when you create and setup the build configuration with compiler-linker options, you need to create macro definition for your code and pass it to compiler with other options. Use this macro to recognize type of library in code.

The compiler command:

```
gcc -D LINK_STATIC a.cpp ...
```

The code:

```
#ifdef LINK_STATIC
  ... static implementation ...
#end

#ifdef LINK_DINAMIC
  ... dinamic implementation ...
#end
```